# Can login via ssh, but not system tty

Tags: login, password, authentication, pam

Here's something weird. I can:

```
ssh xyz@localhost
```

provide my password, and login as xyz.

However, I if hit `ctrl-alt-F3` to go to the system prompt, and try to login as the same user xyz I get a "login failed" message and /var/log/auth.log contains one of two messages:

**Wrong password provided:**

```
Dec  4 14:46:00 sparky-ubuntu1 login[32783]: FAILED LOGIN (2) on
'/dev/tty3' FOR 'xyz', Authentication failure
```

**Correct password provided:**

```
Dec  4 14:46:19 sparky-ubuntu1 login[32783]: FAILED LOGIN (3) on
'/dev/tty3' FOR 'xyz', Permission denied
```

... and I'm super duper sure I'm providing the same username and password that works for ssh. (I also tried changing my password to be only characters a-z, and I continue get the same problem.)

Ideas?

Using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Home directory permission problem?

Comment: I don't that that would explain why ssh works.

Comment: Please clarify me, you are on your local machine and trying to open virtual console (tty3) on a remote computer after ssh-ing into the remote computer. Is that right or am i missing something here?

Comment: Two different methods to access a single (local) ubunutu machine: i) ssh, ii) ctrl-alt-F3 to access tty3.